# Is the water pipe / plumbing insulation similar to air conditioner line insulation?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, insulation

I'm trying to change a worn out insulation on the air conditioner outside of the house.

Is the [plumbing insulation](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Frost-King-0-75-in-x-6-ft-Foam-Plumbing-Tubular-Pipe-Insulation/1001277278) similar to the insulation on the cold AC line (refrigerant line?) on the unit outside of the house? Can you interchange them?

If they are the same, [foam](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Frost-King-0-75-in-x-6-ft-Foam-Plumbing-Tubular-Pipe-Insulation/1001277278) vs [rubber](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Frost-King-3-4-in-x-6-ft-Rubber-Plumbing-Tubular-Pipe-Insulation/3132415)? Which is better in terms of thermal performance?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is meant by "Better"? UV resistance? Rat resistance? Ease of use? Thermal performance?

Comment: Thank you for viewing. I apologize for being unclear. I'm trying to change a worn out insulation on the air conditioner outside of the house. @Solar Mike: Better in thermal performance.

Comment: @Student it's always better to [edit] info like that into your question. People are more likely to see it in the question (not everyone reads comments) and comments can be deleted, losing that info for all time.

Answer (score 2):

Some appears to be "more similar" (*i.e.* virtually all the refrigeration lines I've seen are black rubber insulation, and that type of insulation is also sold for plumbing pipes) but there might be differences (such as the insulation being thicker, or more resistant to sunlight as it's expected to be outside, etc.) despite that apparent similarity. Local practices may also vary depending on local conditions (pest attack, etc.)

Comment: For whatever minor price difference there may be, it would certainly make sense to buy a product listed & rated for outdoor use on AC line sets for replacement of the insulation on an outdoor AC line set. Sure, a few bucks might be saved by buying something cheaper. Until it has to be replaced in 2 years instead of 20.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I was thinking if it's the same, I don't have to go too far to my local Lowe's; vs, hvac parts store. But, I'll make the trip to the hvac parts store just to be sure. Thanks again.